# Show byte representation of primitive values in C

Tags: c

learning C and now i study simple code snipper that show byte representation of primitive values:

```
typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer;

void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf(" %.2x", start[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void show_float(float x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(float));
}

void show_int(int x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_pointer(void *x) {
    show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(void *));
}
```

If i understand correct, `&x` (an ampersand character) showing address of memory (equal to `*x`).

So. program routine is showing hexadecimal values of each data type, with `int` value of bytes like (`sizeof(int))`.

Im not really understand how its work. First, we `typedef` pointer of unsigned char, and then use it with other types. What is the meaning of `(byte_pointer) &x` and why does it work, when we define byte_pointer as value of type `unsigned char`? I understand that we get address of memory that contain value, but i don't know how exactly it work and WHY it work with char pointer. Could you explain that part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code simply takes the address of a random chunk of data and prints the contents byte by byte. The code takes the address of whatever you pass to it, then converts it to a pointer-to-byte (unsigned char). Any pointer type in C can be converted to another pointer type, although in some cases doing so is dangerous practice. In the case of `char`, it is safe though, you are guaranteed to get a pointer to the lowest addressed byte of the object.

Note that hiding a pointer behind a typedef is bad and dangerous practice. Just forget about that typedef, it adds nothing of value. A better way to write the same code would be:

```
void show_bytes (const uint8_t* start, int len)
```

or alternatively

```
void show_bytes (const void* s, int len)
{
  const uint8_t* start = s;
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you Lundin now i understand, And thank for notice about typedef and pointer. It actually confusing for me, thats right.

Answer (score 1):

`byte_pointer` is defined to be a *pointer* to an `unsigned char`; this is so `show_bytes` can print out each individual byte (in hexadecimal) of what the address passed to `show_bytes` points to.

I would have declared `start` to be a `void*`, and then cast it inside of `show_bytes`, making it a) clearer that `show_bytes` doesn't care what type of thing `start` points to, and b) avoids the cast in every call.

Comment: Thank you Scott, not its clear for me. Code is not mine, I'm just study it:)